# Redirect all subdomains to a file except existing files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What I try to achieve is, how can I alias all subdomains to a file except existing files,

The code below, with hashs working but I can't access to files, files also redirecting to "site.php"
But when I remove the hashs then condition is not working. What is the correct way

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . site.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /site.php [L]
```

I've omitted the directory check as you specified everything except existing *files*

Comment: Yes but this is redirecting to the site.php, Page shouldn't be shown. My misatake on question sorry.

Comment: OK, made an edit. Try removing the `R` flag from the rewrite.